# Are macros fully expanded at compile time in Common Lisp?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I was having a problem with macroexpansions that I think I have reduced to the following simplest example (not what I am trying to do but this replicates the errors):

```
(defmacro tester (f &rest args)
  (cond
    ((not (listp args))  `(,f ,args))
    ((= (length args) 1) `(,f ,(car args)))
    (t (loop for arg in args
             collect `(tester ,f ,@arg) into results
             finally (return `(list ,@results))))))
```

When I evaluate

```
(tester (lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) (1 2) 2 3)
```

in the REPL, I get `((2 3) 3 4)` as expected. However, if I instead wrap the code in a function or try to compile it,

```
Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  (TESTER (LAMBDA (A) (+ 1 A)) . 1)
Compile-time error:
  (TESTER (LAMBDA (A) (+ 1 A)) . 1) is not a proper list.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

Why can I evaluate the code just fine but I cannot compile it/put it inside a function definition?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, yes, macros are fully expanded during compilation in CL.  See [minimal compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bbb.htm).

However your macro definition is broken.  If it has more than one argument it collects a series of forms like `(tester ,f ,@arg)`: such a thing is ill-formed unless each such `arg` is a list, which not all your arguments are.  See [2.4.6](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dg.htm):

> If a comma is immediately followed by an at-sign, then the form following the at-sign is evaluated to produce a list of objects. These objects are then "spliced" into place in the template.

Here is a variant of your `tester` macro which is at least correct, using a local function to deal with the recursive expansion.

```
(defmacro tester (f &rest arguments)
  (labels ((et (args)
             `(list ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                (typecase arg
                                  (list (et arg))
                                  (t `(,f ,arg))))
                              args))))
    (et arguments)))
```

Note that this is *not* quite the same as your macro: `(tester (lambda ...) . 1)` isn't legal syntax for this version.  However I am assuming that this case was only present in yours because the recursive expansion was producing it, and you never actually used the macro that way.  It would be possible to make it be legal of course:

```
(defmacro tester (f . arguments)
  (labels ((et (args)
             `(list ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                (typecase arg
                                  (list (et arg))
                                  (t `(,f ,arg))))
                              args))))
    (typecase arguments
      (list (et arguments))
      (t `(,f ,arguments)))))
```

But I think that unless this dotted syntax is something you actively wish to use in source (and then the question would be: why?) you should disallow it as my first variant does.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tester` macro iteratively generates more calls to itself similar to  `(tester (lambda ...) . 2)`.  This should work; the `test` macro should be invoked, and the `2` should be taken by the `&rest` parameter.

Looks like your Lisp implementation has broken handling for macro calls which are dotted forms.

This is required by ANSI CL!

> [3.4.4. Macro Lambda Lists](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_3-4-4.html)

> [...]

> It is permissible for a macro form (or a subexpression of a macro form) to be a dotted list only when (... &rest var) or (... . var) is used to match it. It is the responsibility of the macro to recognize and deal with such situations. )

The macro-expansion performed by `eval` accepts it. I can compile this file:

```
(defmacro tester (f . args)
  (cond
    ((not (listp args)) `(,f ,args))
    ((= (length args) 1) `(,f ,(car args)))
    (t (loop for arg in args
         collect `(tester ,f ,@arg) into results
         finally (return `(list ,@results))))))
 
 (princ (eval '(tester (lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) (1 2) 2 3)))
```

But not with just:

```
(princ (tester (lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) (1 2) 2 3)))
```

It has nothing to do with the macro definition. Even if I change the macro to look like this:

```
(defmacro tester (f . args) ...)
```

The compiler simply won't allow it to be invoked with dotted syntax. I'd file a bug report, since this is required by ANSI CL.

As a workaround, there are hacks you can do, like using `macroexpand` or `eval` inside your macro to evaluate the generated code. This seems to work for me:

```
(defmacro tester (&environment env f . args)
  (cond
    ((not (listp args)) `(,f ,args))
    ((= (length args) 1) `(,f ,(car args)))
    (t (loop for arg in args
         collect (macroexpand `(tester ,f ,@arg) env) into results
         finally (return `(list ,@results))))))
 
 (princ (tester (lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) (1 2) 2 3))
```

All I did was call `macroexpand` on the generated `(tester ...)` code so that the macro itself does the expansion recursively rather than returning the code and letting the macro expander iterate on it.  By doing this, we have evaded the compiler's macro expander, relying on the fact that `macroexpand` doesn't have the issue.

I don't suspect we need the `&environment` call in this particular `macroexpand` call, because we are not expanding a piece of code handed to us as an argument. I put it in there just in case.

Another workaround is to write the expander as a function, like this. For a complex, recursively-defined macro, this is often a good design anyway:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun tester-expander (f args)
    (cond
      ((not (listp args)) `(,f ,args))
      ((= (length args) 1) `(,f ,(car args)))
      (t (loop for arg in args
           collect (tester-expander f arg) into results
           finally (return `(list ,@results)))))))
         
(defmacro tester (f . args)
  (tester-expander f args))
 
 (princ (tester (lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) (1 2) 2 3))
```

Note that now we just have a simple recursive call in the `collect` clause; we don't use a backquote template there.

Also, because this helper is an internal API, we don't have to make `args` a `&rest` parameter. That's just something in the macro syntax, not relevant to the expansion mechanism.

About the `eval-when`, in Common Lisp, macro helper functions have to be wrapped in that ritual. This tells the file compiler "hey, don't just compile this function and stick it into the compiled file, but also define it for yourself" which is needed since the compiler will be invoking the macro.  No such thing is needed around `defmacro` forms, because it is overwhelmingly common for macros to be needed by the compiler in processing the rest of the file.

*Note: I've not considered whether your code makes any sense, but only addressed myself to the issue of why it can be evaluated interactively but not compiled.*

Comment: The dotted macro form can only occur when the requirements of `,@` have already been violated however.

Comment: @ignisvolens I don't think so; the `,@` can splice an atom into the dot position. Just like `(append '(1 2 3) 4)` produces `(1 2 3 . 4)`.  In fact, oh, if we follow the quote-list-append based backquote reference model in the spec (2.4.6), we can see that `\`(... ,@form ...)` is interpreted as `(append ... form ...)` where if `form` is the last element in the `append` call, it can produce an atom.  What you can't have is `,@` not enclosed in a list, or `,@` in the dotted position, which is a different problem.

Comment: it can't.  From 2.4.6: 'If a comma is immediately followed by an at-sign, then the form following the at-sign is evaluated to produce *a list of objects*. These objects are then "spliced" into place in the template.' (my emphasis).

Comment: @ignisvolens That looks like a flaw in the spec. Remember, that CL goes out of its way to allow `(append '(1 2 3)  4)` and the `append` function is the basis for the reference model for backquote expansion. In any case, that isn't the issue that's happening in the code, which is inserting the atom into the dot position just fine via `,@`.

Comment: In a Lisp that doesn't like `(... ,@form)` evaluating to an atom,  it can be very simply replaced by `(... . ,form)` to work around that.

Comment: I'll take the unambiguously-worded English over the untested (and untestable) pseudocode in the spec, I think.  But that's a choice, obviously.